# how do i create a program to loop through videos in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am pretty new to coding, I am trying to apply different seriously.js effects on different arrays of videos, I am not even able to make the program loop through the videos in the array

Here is the work
https://editor.p5js.org/ogierpaul/sketches/EeYFA5Vq_

```
let vid1= 'footb1.mp4';
let vid2= 'footb3.mp4';
let vid3= 'futball1.mp4';

b = [];
b = [vid1,vid2,vid3];

function preload() {
  for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
    q = createVideo(b[j]);
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640,480, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}
```

Comment: please i need assitance with this and a good explanation to help me understand

Comment: Hello, please look how question are asked and give minimal code (without image or link), input and expected output / current output

Comment: please update your post and avoid posting your code in comment.

Comment: I am pretty new to this whole thing, I followed the coding train video, and was able to do the seriously.js program using capture with my webcam,  I intend to try it with imported videos in an array, and a blank canvas keeps showing, please be kind enough to check up on the p5.js link, as the stack flow setup is refusing me posting the copied code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the fundamental thing you're misunderstanding here is how to add items to an array:

```
let vid1= 'footb1.mp4';
let vid2= 'footb3.mp4';
let vid3= 'futball1.mp4';

// I think you probably meant to declare q here not b
let q = []; // previously: b = [];
let b = [vid1,vid2,vid3];

function preload() {
  for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
    // as you create each new video you need to add it to the q array
    // you can do this using the push() function or using the index operator
    q[j] = createVideo(b[j]);
    // q.push(createVideo(b[j])); // this would also work
    // What you had would not work: q = createVideo(b[j]);
    // because it would replace the array initially stored in the variable q with
    // a single video
  }
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(640,480, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
}
```